# Where does Copy item link to clipboard apply?

Tags: 2013-sp1

The Tridion 2013 SP1 [documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-A7BDAA1A-0F33-41E6-9E3B-35CF1984B77F) describes `Copy item link to clipboard` as a Content Manager Explorer ribbon command with this description:

> Put a link to the currently selected item in the list, or the item
>   currently open in this dialog, in your clipboard so that you can paste
>   it in another application or document.

[image: Copy item link to clipboard]
*(source: [SDL Live Content](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-A7BDAA1A-0F33-41E6-9E3B-35CF1984B77F))*

This also appears in the [2011 documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_22DC7C0A376441F39B1E33C95C74183A).

Which tab should this appear in and when does it apply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a string search in 2011 sp1 Tridion directory to find the reference, but i could found "Copy item link to clipboard" only in help file no where else. so it seems its not implemented. but i could find string reference for other e.g "Send Item Link to Email"

Comment: Yeah, I searched the documentation. Sure you don't want to also check every screen in the CME and XPM, just to be sure? ;-)

Comment: i spent only few minutes, did "find in files" @ %Tridion_home%  using notepad++ :), so i mean to say there were references of other features in some files, but feature in your question is only available in documentation installed as part of Tridion installation.

Comment: Just to be sure, was the reference you found an explanation of the feature, or the ability to copy references in the documentation itself?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, this  link does not exists in the Tridion system - neither in 2011 nor in 2013. It seems some sort of messing around, as even when we try to copy an Item it says that the item is copied to the clipboard which is not true as the item is not copied to the clipboard but with in the Tridion CME only.

Write now there is only two functionlities available related to the Item Link:

- Send Item Link to Favourite
- Send Item Link to Email

To copy the Item link to Clipboard we either need to open it and copy the browser URL or Send it to the Email and then copy the link from there.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the *copy item link* button **should** appears on the home tab, under *send from link* on the right hand side of the navigation panel. However it is not there.

[image]

It should apply when you have any linkable item highlighted or open, for example (Page, Component, etc...)

The highlight on the left is the regular *copy item* button

Comment: That is the Copy Item and Send to Email icons and not one specified in the question (Copy Item Link to Clipboard)

Comment: Yes, I don't think the one mentioned exists. It should exist next to the other "send item link" items like "send by email"

Comment: Ohh, I understood now :)

Comment: Yeah, +1--this is where I expected to find the feature. I also checked in the rich text format (RTF) area and schema field RTF options. I `Copy Item Link to Clipboard` is either a *potential* feature or maybe a documentation (Copy & Paste!) error. Maybe it's from a related module or other SDL software. I'll leave a comment on SDL Live Content to be sure.